# AQuery 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: android, android-async-http, aquery

When I use AsyncHttpClient to get response from my request URL(Using GET method), it works fine. Now I am trying to use AQuery library, and get 405 error. How can I deal with this problem? My code:

```
public void queryAPI(String url, Map<String, Object> params, final ObjectCallback success, final ObjectCallback failure) {

    if (params == null) {
        params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }

    aq.ajax(baseUrl, params, JSONObject.class, new AjaxCallback<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void callback(String url, JSONObject data, AjaxStatus status) {

                    Log.e("Status", status.getCode() + " " +status.getMessage());
                    if (data != null) 
                          success.process(null);
                    failure.process(null);
                }
            }.method(Constants.METHOD_GET).header("Authorization","authValue").header("User-Agent", "android"));
}
```